# For a given integer n, what is the cardinality of the greatest subset of (1,n) such that no element of the subset divides another element?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

i.e. Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$, what is the greatest cardinality of $B\subset A$ s.t. no element in $B$ divides another element in $B$. Preferably using pigeonhole principle.

Comment: What have you tried?  An obvious first thought would be to write out the answers for small $n$.

Comment: This is specifically for a few n's around 2000, so I was wondering if there was a general principle I could use to develop them given an arbitrary n.

Comment: And the best way to get an understanding is to work the same problem for small $n$.

Comment: @lulu had initially given away the answer, but edited the comment to remove it.

Comment: @DonThousand  In truth, my first guess was wrong. You can do much better than the set of primes $≤n$.  For $n=2m$ you can find a set with $m$ elements that works.

Comment: This well known [Putnam Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/using-pigeonhole-principle-to-prove-two-numbers-in-a-subset-of-2n-divide-eac) is similar and relevant.

Comment: @lulu I found the correct approach (I think). Iterate from $n\to1$, and check whether the given element is a divisor of any of the elements in the subcollection you are generating (at the beginning, it is empty). If it isn't, add it to the subcollection.

Comment: @DonThousand  That's how I was thinking at first, but it's simpler than that.  At least for even $n=2m$.  Pigeonhole tells us that $m+1$ fails and its easy to  do $m$.  I haven't thought about odd $n$ but it has to be more or less the same.

Comment: @lulu I think it's exactly the same for $2n+1$, since the elements $n+1\to2n+1$ work, while any more clearly doesn't by pigeonhole.

Comment: @DonThousand  Agreed, it's not materially different.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, all we need is a minor addition to an earlier [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/using-pigeonhole-principle-to-prove-two-numbers-in-a-subset-of-2n-divide-eac)

Suppose first that $n=2m$. Clearly the subset $m+1,\dots,2m$ works. Now make pigeonholes for $k=1,\dots,m$, so that the pigeonhole for $k$ contains all numbers $(2k-1)2^r$ (with $r\ge0)$) from $A$. Between them the pigeonholes contain the whole of $A$ and we can pick at most one number from each pigeonhole.

For $n=2m+1$, again the subset $m+1,\dots,2m+1$ works. Now we know we cannot pick more than $m$ from $1,2,\dots,2m$, so we cannot pick more than $m+1$ from $1,2,\dots,2m+1$.