# What is the size of the largest subset of integers less than n, such that no number divides any other?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

What is the size of the largest subset of integers less or equal than n, such that no number divides any other?

For example if n is 10 we can pick 3,4,5,6,7,10 to get a set of size 6.

Edit: my example is wrong as pointed out in the comments as 3 divides 6 and 5 divides 10

Comment: 3 divides 6, though.

Comment: And $5$ divides $10.$

Comment: Well, it's atleast $\pi(n).$ We can make a subset containing all the primes less than or equal to $n,$ and no element will divide any other element in that subset.

Comment: $6,7,8,9,10$ maybe? The largest size is at least $n/2-1$ for even $n$ and $(n+1)/2$ for odd $n$.

Comment: For your case of $n=10,$ consider $\{2,3,5,7\}.$ This is the "prime-subset" I was talking about.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut is right. The elements in the "second-half" of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$ cannot divide each other. This idea needs to be made precise though. Also, I am not sure if a bigger subset could somehow exist. Maybe some modular arithmetic would help.

Comment: And I think it's optimal, using pigeonhole's principle.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut FYI, you're correct, including that the pigeon-hole principle is one way to prove it, e.g., as shown with the odd part (i.e., with all factors of $2$ removed) of each chosen integer in [For a given integer n, what is the cardinality of the greatest subset of (1,n) such that no element of the subset divides another element?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3515274/602049), with this being the top item in a [site search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=no+integer+divides+another).